# Does Thread.sleep() use the same clock as System.nanoTime()

Tags: java, time, blocking

*This question is about the relation between library functions that do some kind of wait, e.g. `Thread.sleep(long)`, `Object.wait(long)`, `BlockingQueue.poll(long, TimeUnit)`, and the values returned by `System.nanoTime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()`.*

As I understand, there are at least two, mostly independent clocks a Java application has access to:

- `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which is basically the *Wall Clock Time*, which also means that the user and system software like an *NTP* daemon may fiddle with it from time to time, possibly leading to that value jumping around in any direction and amount.
- `System.nanoTime()` which is guaranteed to be monotonically and more or less steadily increasing, but may drift because of not-so-accureate processor clock frequencies and artifacts caused by power saving mechanisms.

Now I understand that library functions like `Thread.sleep()` need to rely on some platform-dependent interface to suspend a thread until the specified amount of time has passed, but is it safe to assume that the time measured by these functions is based on the values of `System.nanoTime()`?

I know that none of these functions guarantee to measure time more accurately than a few milliseconds, but I am interested about very long (as in hours) waits. I.e. if I call `Thread.sleep(10 * 3600 * 1000)` the time measured between the two clocks can differ by a few minutes but I assume that one of them will be within a fraction of a second of the requested 10 hours. And if any of the two clocks is, I'm assuming its the one used by `System.nanoTime()`. Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: Don't rely on very long waits, it's perfectly fine for a thread to wake up every minute or so and check the time.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not safe to assume that it Thread.sleep is based on System.nanoTime.

Java relies on the OS to perform thread scheduling, and it has no control over how the OS performs it.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, time based APIs that existed pre-jdk 1.5 (Timer, Thread.sleep, wait(long)) all use milliseconds based time.  Most of the concurrency utils added in jdk 1.5+ (java.util.concurrent.*) use the nano based time.

However, i don't think the jvm guarantees these behaviors, so you certainly shouldn't depend on behavior one way or the other.